# Android Margin and Padding aren't working for RecyclerViews inside ScrollViews

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

When I place a RecyclerView as a child of a ScrollView, `marginBottom` and `paddingBottom` doesn't work. Setting these values for the parent `LinearLayout` doesn't affect anything either. It seems that the `ScrollView` doesn't scroll to the bottom because the `ScrollBar` doesn't reach the bottom. How can I fix this bug?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!--To avoid scroll view from scrolling to the bottom automatically-->
<View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/focus_view" android:layout_height="0dp" android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"><requestFocus/></View>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv_categories_statistics"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_categories_statistics_filters_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_categories_statistics_select_date_fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/border_primary_light"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/border_accent"
                android:padding="4dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spn_categories_statistics_bill_type"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/pc_categories_statistics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="325dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fgm_categories_statistics_not_enough_data"
        class="com.dolinsek.elias.cashcockpit.NotEnoughDataFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:text="@string/label_not_enough_data_for_statistic"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_categories_statistics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `clipToPadding`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_categories_statistics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

Comment: It worked but the `RecyclerView` doesn't show all items now

Comment: try `scrollview android:layout_height` match or wrap. Remove scrollview `layout_weight`